# Print out certain text from string with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to get a certain string from an .torrent name but I'm only getting this from it:

```
array
  0 => string 'e' (length=1)
```

What have I done wrong? This is the `preg_match` I use:

`preg_match('/[S(0-9)E(0-9)]/i', 'True.Blood.S04E12.SWESUB.PDTV.XviD-DSMEDiA', $matches);`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the square brackets and put them around the numbers and add `+` (meaning 1 or more) after them. This way you get the entire S##E## string, plus the numbers separately:

```
preg_match('/S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+)/i', 'True.Blood.S04E12.SWESUB.PDTV.XviD-DSMEDiA', $matches);
print_r($matches);
/* output:
Array
(
    [0] => S04E12
    [1] => 04
    [2] => 12
)
*/
```

You could also replace `[0-9]` with `\d`

Comment: Many thanks! This worked like a charm :) I'm kinda new to Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using:

```
preg_match('/S[0-9]{1,2}E[0-9]{1,2}/i', 'True.Blood.S04E12.SWESUB.PDTV.XviD-DSMEDiA', $matches);
```

It gets out this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "S04E12" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will return the appropriate string.

```
/* Pattern:  /\d{2}E\d{2}/   */
preg_match_all('/\d{2}E  \d{2}/', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
/*Result*/
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 04E12
        )

)
```